# How to check if variable is String type

Tags: coffeescript

I'm getting data with ajax, and the result can be either array of results or a string statement like "no results found". How can i tell whether i got any results or not? 
i tried this approach:

```
if result == String
    do something
```

but its not working, just like

```
if typeof(result) == "string"
    do something
```

Is there any other function that can help me get the type of the variable? Or maybe i can test it for Array type, it would also be very helpful

Answer (score 33):

use `typeof`

```
doSomething(result) if typeof result is 'string'
```

Note that `typeof` is an operator not a function so you don't write `typeof(result)`

You can also do this

```
doSomethingElse(result) if typeof result isnt 'string'
```

or even

```
return if typeof result is 'string'
   doSomething result
else
   doSomethingElse result
```

See http://coffeescript.org/#conditionals for more on `Coffeescript` conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

### Check that the result is a String:

This can be done in the way that many common [libraries](http://underscorejs.org/#isString) do it:

```
isString = (obj) -> toString.call(obj) == '[object String]'
```

### Check that the result is an Array:

You can also try to use the native `Array.isArray` function, and fall back to
a similar style of type checking as used above:

```
isArray = Array.isArray or (obj) -> toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
if Object.prototype.toString.call(result) == '[object String]'
    do something
```